# Why under /bin are there so many ‘Unix executable files’?

Tags: macos, file

Why under `/bin` are there so many Alias and Unix executable files? I thought executable files were files that Mac categorize as "not used" or along those lines?

Answer (score 1):

macOS [is UNIX.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1489/45383) macOS [is POSIX-certified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX-certified). `/bin` contains common binaries needed by macOS and is absolutely required for the correct functioning of the OS.

I guess what you're confusing is how these files are represented in Finder. In Finder, the file type of binaries are shown as ‘Unix executable’. Executable files as you may know them are probably .exe for Windows, which are not something macOS can execute. They are still referred to as executable files, since just because macOS can't execute them doesn't mean there isn't something else that can.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you said... but "why and what else can" execute these files and why I cannot remove these files? (The weird thing is that most of these files do occur or were modified on the same week day....) - thanks...

Comment: @Lost I'm not sure I understand, but Windows can execute .exe files and macOS can execute Unix executable files. You can't remove the files because they're used by the operating system, that's like trying to remove dlls/System32 (I'm not a Windows guy, close enough). They have similar modification dates because installing the OS installs those files, so they would be installed together.

Comment: macOS can execute them as well as applications that may use them as well. You can execute them yourself and manually do what the system might automatically do. Do not try and remove any of them, macOS will likely prevent you from doing this but don't even try as they are necessary to the operation of macOS